# Leetcode 137: Single Number II -- python bit operations

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise

I solved [LeetCode 137](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii) in C++. TLDR of the problem: array of numbers, `nums` is given; all numbers appear 3 times, except one which appear only once. Find the number that appears once.

When trying to convert my [C++ solution](https://github.com/mcimpoi/coding_practice_public/blob/main/leetcode/cpp/P0137_SingleNumber.cpp) to python, I came across few funny things, i.e. the bit operations seem to behave a bit differently in python, on negative integers.

So, I switched to using formatting as binary string - but, to my surprise, INT_MIN (-2^32 - 1) resulted in a string of length 33, containing the sign as well. Where could I read more about this and understand why it happens?

How can I improve the code below, to make it more pythonic?

```py
def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    INT_BASE = 33  # because of INT32_MIN
    # give python what it likes
    counts_nz = [0 for _ in range(INT_BASE)]
    vals_bit = ["0" for _ in range(INT_BASE)]

    for num in nums:
        # 33 because of INT32_MIN takes 33 bits to represent.
         for idx, bin_val in enumerate(f"{num:033b}"):
             if bin_val != "0":  # can be "1" or "-"
                 counts_nz[idx] += 1
                 vals_bit[idx] = bin_val

         # make the bits binary string -- set to value for M3 + 1 and 0 otherwise
         bin_res = "".join(
             [
                 vals_bit[idx] if count % 3 == 1 else "0"
                 for idx, count in enumerate(counts_nz)
             ]
        )

        return int(bin_res, 2)
```

Comment: With immutable types: use the * operator instead of list comprehension. `[0] * INT_BASE` and `['0'] * INT_BASE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> INT_MIN

Yeah, python doesn't really expose a "machine integer" concept.
[Page 5](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/Moon-MACLISP_Reference_Manual-Apr_08_1974.pdf)
of the 1974 MACLISP manual explained

> it is impossible to get "overflow" in [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) arithmetic ...

Now if C code assigns `int16 n = 32767` and then `n++` increments,
we [may](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++)
get the most negative int rather than 32768.
Which is fine by programmers but makes mathematicians a bit cross.

In python the sign bit is entirely separate.

The bit counting trick is nice, I like it.
Here is an implementation of that which treats the sign bit seperately.
Also, [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks for a snake_case function name.
And `List[int]` works but in modern interpreters
we prefer a lower `list[int]` annotation.

```
import random
import unittest

from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st


def single_number(nums: list[int]) -> int:
    res = 0

    for bit in range(32):
        counts = sum(num < 0 for num in nums)
        mask = 1 << bit
        for num in nums:
            if abs(num) & mask:
                counts += 1
        if counts % 3 == 1:
            res |= mask

    BIAS = 2**31
    if res >= BIAS:  # caller will need to see a negative result
        res -= (2 * BIAS - 1)

    return res


class TestLeet137(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_leet137(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, single_number([2, 2, 3, 2]))
        self.assertEqual(0, single_number([2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0]))
        self.assertEqual(-99, single_number([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -99]))

    def test_negative_binary(self):
        num = -6
        self.assertEqual("-00000000000000000000000000000110", f"{num:033b}")


# These constants are specified by https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii
LO = -(2**31)
HI = 2**31 - 1


@given(st.lists(st.integers(min_value=LO, max_value=HI), min_size=1))
def test_leet(randoms: list[int]):
    target, *distractors = randoms
    arg = [target] + distractors * 3
    assert single_number(arg) == target

    arg.sort()
    assert single_number(arg) == target

    random.shuffle(arg)
    assert single_number(arg) == target
```

The loop effectively produces a 32-bit machine word,
so we clean up at the end in order to
properly return a negative result.

Also in the 2nd test I was highlighting
the not-very-binary {"-", "0", "1"} bits
you were getting from that string conversion.

This might be a good opportunity to import
[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int32) or
[fixedint](https://pypi.org/project/fixedint).

---

Given that we need to apply a bias anyway,
it seems more convenient to operate on strictly
non-negative numbers:

```
def single_number(nums: list[int]) -> int:
    BIAS = 2**31
    nums = [num + BIAS for num in nums]
    assert all(num >= 0 for num in nums)

    res = 0

    for bit in range(32):
        counts = 0
        mask = 1 << bit
        for num in nums:
            if abs(num) & mask:
                counts += 1
        if counts % 3 == 1:
            res |= mask

    return res - BIAS
```

No loop change after the `counts` assignment -- we're just
removing negatives up front and then re-adjusting at end.
Well, ok, I suppose that pasted `abs()` is superfluous
and should be deleted.